# Retrieving "two option" field value on the plugin in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Am trying to update child contacts based on a "Two Options" field in the account form. I update all child contacts to the updated address of parent account if the "Two Option" field is set to "Yes".
I try to retrieve the value using the following code,

```csharp
bool? updateContactsValue 
  = entity.GetAttributeValue<bool?>("abc_yesNoField");

if (updateContactsValue)
{
  String[] details = new string[7];
  String telephoneNum = String.Empty, ... , country = String.Empty;

  telephoneNum = entity.GetAttributeValue<String>("telephone1");
  details[0] = telephoneNum;
  ...

  UpdateContact(service, entity.Id, details);
}
```

But i find that the address fields are not being updated even if the selected option is "Yes". Am i missing something here?

Hi all, 
I have modified the code to as follows

```csharp
bool? updateContactsValue=null; 
updateContactsValue = entity.GetAttributeValue<bool?> ("abc_yesNoField").GetValueOrDefault();

throw new Exception( "My custom Exception"+" "+entity.GetAttributeValue<bool?>("abc_yesNoField").GetValueOrDefault().ToString());
```

The system throws "false" even if I had chosen "Yes".

Comment: I took the liberty of heavily downsize your code to illustrate the essential part of the problem. Hope you like it.

Comment: is better you do a simple
var value = entity["abc_yesNoField"];
to retrieve the real field value, try to throw the execption with this variable

Comment: I bet that if you intentionally misspell the name of the field, you'll get the same behavior. Check it, please. Also, could you line-brake the examples a little better, please?

Comment: Hi, I did try my best to format my question.Thanks Guido, I did follow your idea of throwing an exception to see what value i was getting, and I was getting "false" even if "Yes" was chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you wrote wrong your field name, it can't be "updatechildcontacts".
Because is a custom field it must starts with a prefix, like new_updatechildcontacts

Comment: Thank you, but I do have the prefix in place, i just removed it here.

Comment: In this case you need to debug the plugin (or throw an exception if the plugin is registered synchronous) to see which value you are getting

Answer (score 1):

It's just a shot from the hip, because I'm not at the computer right now, but I'm fairly sure that you (for some reason that I can't tell right now), fail to fetch the value and get the *bool* to be null. And the execution of the update is conditioned by it being *true*.

You need to check the value of the field in a different way.

I'm not sure but I'd expect the yes/no element to be a *bool* and not a *nullable bool*. What happens if you go like this? Does it compile?

```csharp
bool updateContactsValue 
  = entity.GetAttributeValue<bool>("abc_yesNoField");

if (updateContactsValue) { ... }
```

Comment: That was my initial try, it did not work.Also my early bound class page has nullable bool as the return type. So thought of having Nullable Bool Type itself.

Comment: Hmm... I haven't done much with early bound so I'm a bit unsure. What do you mean by "it didn't work, by the way"?

Comment: I mean I had the exact lines that you have mentioned above,the child contacts did not update as expected. It did not throw an error though.

Comment: I mean - in what way did it not work? What was the problem you had? I'm asking because **maybe** the issue is with your classes.

Comment: I mean I had the exact lines that you have mentioned above,the child contacts did not update as expected. It did not throw an error though.

Comment: Two suggestions, then. Either the order of yes/no is reverted somehow so that *yes* is *false* and *no* is *true* or (as Guido suggests) there's a problem with the name (which you replied it's not). Would you mind rechecking the exact spelling?

Comment: I did check the spelling. It seems to be right, I mean its the same.Kindly check my edits in the question, it throws false irrespective of what i choose

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the query statement, please make sure that you have inserted your attribute inside it. If it is not inserted it will always give you false value for example:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("ntw_abc");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("ntw_referencenumber", "abc_yesNoField");
```

Answer (score 1):

May be problem is due to that you are using **Scheema Name** i.e mixed case.     **abc_yesNoField** cannot be Name of attribute bcoz it uses mixed case.
It should be LowerCase like **abc_yesnofield**

```
bool? updateContactsValue= entity.GetAttributeValue<bool?>("abc_yesnofield");
```

Always Use **Logical Name** of attribute i.e **Name** (Always lowercase)  in:
1. Xrm
2. c# code late bind

Use **Scheema Name** of attribute i.e (mixed case or camel casing)  in:
1. REST/oData/JSON object model
2. c# early bound classes (LINQ)